# Multiple Image Upload using Vue js with api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload

it is my vue template where i set a template for uploading multiple images. Also here i use @change="handleFileChange"function

```
  <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Product Photos <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="file" ref="fileInput" class="file-upload-default" multiple @change="handleFileChange">
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control file-upload-info" disabled placeholder="Upload Images">
                <span class="input-group-append">
      <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-primary" type="button">Upload</button>
    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="selectedImages.length > 0" class="selected-images">
            <div v-for="(image, index) in selectedImages" :key="index" class="selected-image">
                <img :src="image.url" alt="Selected Image">
                <div class="remove-button">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeImage(index)">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the method of my submit and handleFileChange method in data return i took a value selectedImages: []

```
 handleFileChange(event) {
        const files = event.target.files;
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.selectedImages.push({ url: e.target.result, file: files[i] });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
        // Clear the file input value
        this.$refs.fileInput.value = '';
    },

async submit() {
        try{
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('productName', this.name);
            formData.append('category', this.category);
            // Add entities data to formData
            this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                const entity = {
                    color: item.color,
                    size: item.size,
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                };
                formData.append(`entities[${index}]`, JSON.stringify(entity));
            });
            formData.append('price', this.price);
            formData.append('totalQuantity', this.totalQuantity);
            this.selectedImages.forEach((image, index) => {
                console.log(image.file)
                formData.append(`image[${index}]`, image.file);
            });
            formData.append('caption', this.caption);
            const response = await axios.post('/api/add-product', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
            });

            console.log(response.data);
        }catch (error) {
            console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
        }
    }
```

here is my laravel controller

```
public function addProductDetails(Request $request)
{
    $product = new ProductDetails();
    $images = [];

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        foreach ($request->file('image') as $image) {
            $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $images[] = $imageName;
            $image->move(public_path('ProductImage'), $imageName);
            return 'got photo';
        }
    } else {
        return 'no photo';
    }
}
```

here it always return no photo where i entered multiple photos